# Keeping one (invariant) row from each dataframe group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that I have grouped by a combination of three columns `A, B, C`.

```
grouped = df.groupby(["A", "B", "C"])
```

Several additional columns `D, E, F, G` are (guaranteed) identical for all elements of each group, while other columns `X, Y` vary within each group. (I already know which columns are fixed, and which vary.)

I would like to construct a dataframe containing one row per group, and consisting of the values for the invariant columns `A, B, C, D, E, F, G` only. What is the most straightforward way to do this? Since there are lots of identical values, I would prefer to specify which columns to omit, rather than the other way around.

I've come up with "aggregating" by choosing one row from each group, and then deleting the unwanted columns in a separate step:

```
thinned = grouped.aggregate(lambda x: x.iloc[0])
del thinned["X"], thinned["Y"]
```

The purpose of this is to combine the invariant values with several new summary values that I calculate, in a dataframe that has one row per (current) group.

```
thinned["newAA"] = grouped.apply(some_function)
thinned["newBB"] = grouped.apply(other_function)
...
```

But I suspect there must be a less round-about way.

Comment: why not just not select those columns in the first place prior to `groupby`? e.g. `df[df.columns.difference(['X','Y'])].groupby(['A','B','C'])`

Comment: That's a good idea, but I also need to merge with a dataframe computed on the grouped columns that vary. So it might work, but I need to take some care with the indexing.

Comment: it just seems redundant to me to group and then drop the cols you're not interested in, better to just not select them prior to the operation

Comment: Well I *am* interested in computing values from the dropped columns;  I just also need the invariant columns in the result. Anyway the `difference()` method is good to know about.

Comment: The other thing you can also do is groupby on all the invariant cols anyway and pass `as_index=False` or `reset_index` but if you just want to remove dupes there is already an existing method for this, it depends on what you want to achieve finally.

Comment: What I want to achieve is a table that contains my computed values (one row per group), plus the invariant values from the original dataframe. I guess I should have added that context to the question... I did now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [GroupBy.first()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) to select just the first record of each group. For example, this

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
    'B': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
    'C': [2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1]
})
print(df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].first())
```

results in

```
A  B
1  1    2
2  1    3
   2    3
3  2    1
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[7,4,4],
                   'B':[7,4,4],
                   'C':[7,4,4],
                   'D':[7,4,4],
                   'E':[7,4,4],
                   'F':[7,4,4],
                   'G':[7,4,4],
                   'X':[1,2,8],
                   'Y':[5,7,0]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  X  Y
0  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  1  5
1  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  2  7
2  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  8  0

#filter by subset
cols = ["A", "B", "C", "D","E","F", "G"]
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=cols)[cols]
print (df1)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0  7  7  7  7  7  7  7
1  4  4  4  4  4  4  4

#remove unnecessary columns
df2 = df.drop(['X','Y'], axis=1).drop_duplicates()
print (df2)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0  7  7  7  7  7  7  7
1  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have many option here, more or less elegant.
First of all, do you care of 'X' and 'Y'? If you don't, since you're deleting them at the end you could simply use [drop_duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
new_df = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']].drop_duplicates()
# this will keep only the unique values of the above columns
```